# validating multiple textbox having same name with jquery validator validates only first input

Tags: jquery, forms, jquery-validate

I am trying to validate the two inputs having same name with jquery validator ..

```
<script src='
            http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js '></script>
            <script src='http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.min.js'></script>
            <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){

            $('#frm').validate();

            $("[name=inp_text]").each(function(){
            $(this).rules("add", {
            required: true,
            checkValue: true
             });   
           });

                $.validator.addMethod("checkValue", function(value, element) {
                var response = ((value > 0)&&(value <= 100))||((value == 'test1')||(value =='test2'));
               return response;
               }, "invalid value");

            })

            </script>


            <form id='frm' method='post'>
            <input type='text' name='inp_text'/><br>
                <input type='text' name='inp_text'/><br>
            <input type='submit' name=''/>
            </frm>
```

but when I run this code it only validates first inputs and second inputs gets simply ignored

I have also tried using `<input type='text' name='inp_text[]'/><br>` but still not working.

what should I change...?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> *"I am trying to validate the two inputs having same name with jquery
>   validator ..."*

```
<input type='text' name='inp_text'/>
<input type='text' name='inp_text'/>
```

> *"but when I run this code it only validates first inputs and second
>   inputs gets simply ignored"*

You cannot have two `input` fields of `type="text"` with the same `name` or this plugin will not work properly.  The `name` attribute **must** be unique.  *(One exception to the `name` being unique, is that "groupings" of checkbox or radio inputs will share the same `name` as the corresponding submission is a single point of data.  However, the `name` must still be unique to each grouping of checkbox and radio elements.)*

> *"what should I change...?*"

Make each `name` attribute unique.

```
<input type='text' name='inp_text[1]'/>
<input type='text' name='inp_text[2]'/>
```

Then use the "starts with" selector, `^=`...

```
$("[name^=inp_text]").each(function () {
    $(this).rules("add", {
        required: true,
        checkValue: true
    });
});
```

**Working DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/PgLh3/**

**NOTES**:  You can also target elements by `id` when using the `rules('add')` method, however for this case, nothing is solved because the plugin still requires a *unique* `name` on each `input` element.

Comment: Thanks alot .. can you explain me why it was not working when I use inp_txt[] .... whith that name should become unique I suppose.. or am I wrong with this assumption .. ?

Comment: @dreamCoder, because `inp_text[]` is exactly the same as `inp_text[]`.  How would it "become unique"?  I guess I don't fully understand what you're asking.

Comment: There is no such thing as `unique` in the documentation.

Comment: @OzanKurt, it's fairly well known that this documentation is lacking. However, you are free to examine the source code and see for yourself that the `name` attribute is how this plugin keeps track of all form elements being validated.  [Also see this demo where the plugin fails when the `name` attribute is duplicated:   jsfiddle.net/ed3vxgmy/](http://jsfiddle.net/ed3vxgmy/)

Comment: <form id="myform">
    <input type="text" name="field[1]lang[1][name]" />
    <br/>
    <input type="text" name="field[2]lang[2][name]" />
    <br/>
    <input type="submit" />
</form>  How to do

Answer (score 1):

Add a configuration like the following like rules or messages

```
multipleInputSharedName: {
        inp_text: true
    }
```

Change code in jquery.validate.js
Method name: elements

replace the following

```
if ( this.name in rulesCache || !validator.objectLength( $( this ).rules() ) ) {
                return false;
            }
```

with the following

```
if ( (!validator.settings.multipleInputSharedName[this.name] && this.name in rulesCache) || !validator.objectLength( $( this ).rules() ) ) {
                return false;
            }
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes, JQuery validate will only validate first occurrence.
You use different names for textboxes.
OR
You can use same names but different ids.
and apply check according to id.

> $("#myform").validate({   rules: {
>       #id_of_field: {
>         required: true, checkValue: true
>       }   } });

Comment: True, the jQuery Validate plugin will not not work when two fields to contain the same name; only the first field will validate.  However, declaring rules by `id` within `.validate()` is not valid and will absolutely break everything.  See: http://jsfiddle.net/tpg7M

Comment: Sorry dear, you can use following for array names.$('#myform').validate({
  rules : {
    'data[]': { required: true, minlength: 1 }
  }
});

Answer (score -1):

Friends!

In order to validate the text box/checkbox/select with the same name
use the following it is working fine for me.

Here 'ctryId' is the name of the select box.

```
function validateCountry(){
    inp = document.getElementsByTagName("select");
    for ( var i = 0; i < inp.length; ++i )    {
        if (inp[i].name =="ctryId" && inp[i].value==''){
            alert('plesae select a country!');
                return false;
            }
        }
    return true;
 }
```

Here 'minVal' is the name of the text box

```
function validateMinimumVal(){
    inp = document.getElementsByTagName("TEXT");
    for ( var i = 0; i < inp.length; ++i )    {
        if (inp[i].name =="minVal" && inp[i].value==''){
            alert('plesae Add a MINIMUM VALUE!!');
                return false;
            }
        }
    return true;
 }
```

Hope this helps!!
Jagan

Comment: This doesn't answer the intended question.